# Natural Sorting SQL ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Can anyone lend me a hand as to what I should append to my ORDER BY statement to sort these values naturally:

```
1
10
2
22
20405-109
20405-101
20404-100
X
Z
D
```

Ideally I'd like something along the lines of:

```
1
2
10
22
20404-100
20405-101
20405-109
D
X
Z
```

I'm currently using:

```
ORDER BY t.property, l.unit_number
```

where the values are `l.unit_number`

I've tried doing `l.unit_number * 1` and `l.unit_number + 0` but they haven't worked.

Should I be doing sort of `ORDER` conditional, such as `Case When IsNumeric(l.unit_number)`?

Thank you.

Comment: How do you expect `20405-109` and `X` to be treated?

Comment: I added the desired output. Apologizes. Knew I forgot something.

Comment: 20405-109 can be strigified and come before or after the Alpha's. It's pretty lenient. I just want like things to sort properly. 1->2->3->10->11->20->21, A->B->C->D, etc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will do it:

```
SELECT value
FROM Table1
ORDER BY value REGEXP '^[A-Za-z]+$'
        ,CAST(value as SIGNED INTEGER)
        ,CAST(REPLACE(value,'-','')AS SIGNED INTEGER)
        ,value
```

The 4 levels of `the ORDER BY`:

1. `REGEXP` assigns any alpha line a 1 and non-alphas a 0
2. `SIGNED INT` Sorts all of the numbers by the portion preceding the dash.
3. `SIGNED INT` after removing the dash sorts any of the items with the same value before the dash by the portion after the dash. Potentially could replace number 2, but wouldn't want to treat 90-1 the same as 9-01 should the case arise.
4. Sorts the letters alphabetically.

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a981/17/0)

Comment: Wow, that works amazingly well. Thank you! I've never done a complex ORDER BY, this will give me something to think on

Comment: how is performance impacted?