# SQL table ORDER BY with the column name having numbers

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-order-by

I want to fetch data a SQL table with ASC order. But, the Columns has values like

```
Route 1
Route 2
Route 3
Route 10
Route 11 etc.
```

So, when I use `ORDER BY ASC`, it will arrange as

```
Route 1
Route 10
Route 11
Route 2
Route 3 etc.
```

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: you need a natural sort, but haven't told us which DB you're using.

Comment: Actually, I am using SQLite

Comment: Duplicate of [Natural Sorting SQL ORDER BY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354217/natural-sorting-sql-order-by)?

Comment: Do all the strings begin with "ROUTE "?  Is every character after "ROUTE " a numeric character?  If so, how about `ORDER BY CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(columnName,7,LEN(columnName)-6))`

Comment: It is getting ordered this way since the data type is varchar and not int. You need to extract the number part and cast it to an integer for ordering. Something like ORDER BY Convert(int, Column).

Comment: Thank you all, I will try your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQLite, the syntax for extracting a substring and converting it into a number is:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY CAST(substr(MyColumn, 7) AS INT)
```