# Natural sorting in SQL does not work

Tags: mysql, sql, natural-sort

I am trying to sort a row "naturally" in SQL, and I found this answer which supposedly does exactly what I need:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17354420/7563153

But when I tried recreating it in "SQL Fiddle" I couldn't get it to work...

[Here's my attempt](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a4db/1/0)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please insert relevant code directly in your question rather than require people to go to an offsite source.

Comment: If you read carefully the answer explanation you will understand that you have a (completely) different problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between the example you cite and your own trial, is that *your* data combines numeric and non-numeric characters in the same field, so casting to an integer doesn't work (it just gives 0).  You can visualize why the query isn't working for you by adding the `order by` expressions in your select list like this:

```
SELECT test
       ,test REGEXP '^[A-Za-z]+$'
       ,CAST(test as SIGNED INTEGER)
       ,CAST(REPLACE(test,'-','')AS SIGNED INTEGER)
FROM table1
ORDER BY test REGEXP '^[A-Za-z]+$'
        ,CAST(test as SIGNED INTEGER)
        ,CAST(REPLACE(test,'-','')AS SIGNED INTEGER)
        ,test
```

You'll see that they all evaluate to 0, which does not give you the sort order you're looking for.

You need to separate the numeric portion of your value from the non-numeric portion, and sort them separately.  Something like this:

```
SELECT test    
FROM table1
ORDER BY substring_index(test,'-',1)
        ,CAST(substring(test, locate('-', test)+1)AS SIGNED INTEGER)
        ,test
```

You might need to adjust that if your actual data isn't as simple and straightforward as your example data.

Answer (score 0):

For your given database schema, is your attempt even necessary?

Try something like this,

```
SELECT `test`
FROM table1
ORDER BY LENGTH(`test`),
         `test`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming (!) that your data have the format "blabla-integer" with one and only one dash (`-`) separating the alphanumeric part from the integer part I would go this way:

```
select * from table1
order by cast(substring(test, 
                        locate('-', test) + 1, 
                        length(test) - locate('-', test)
                       ) as signed integer
             );
```